# Contact reviewer AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to reach the users that reviewed the app on the AppStore? I have someone reporting some problems and I would like to reach this person to get more information

Comment: Not possible at the moment, I believe. It will be better if you have built-in feedback form in your app. Using MFMailComposeViewController will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feedback from within the app is crucial. Also you can leave a comment yourself and hope this user sees it. Or put a feedback form on your website and solicit comments in the app description.

Comment: No, you cannot leave reviews on your own app to communicate with users.

Comment: Well shucks there goes that